# Why can a force field only be conservative if it is spherically symmetric?

Tags: forces, symmetry, definition, vector-fields, conservative-field

I saw in my textbook that a field can only be conservative if it happens to be spherically symmetric. Why is this so? Is there a good proof for this?

Comment: What definition of "conservative" do you know? It'll help me write an answer :)

Comment: The curl being zero.

Comment: Which textbook? Which page?

Answer (score 4):

No. While a spherically symmetric force field has zero curl and is thus conservative, the converse is not true. As @gandalf61 points out, there can be many, many force-fields that are conservative but not spherically symmetric, I'd urge you to try and construct a couple yourself!

To show why a spherically symmetric field is conervative, here is a very simple one-way proof: a conservative force field $\mathbf{F}$ is one that has zero curl, i.e $$\nabla \times \mathbf{F} = 0.$$

If a force field is spherically symmetric, then it must be written as $\mathbf{F} \equiv F(r)\mathbf{\hat{r}}$. It's now a trivial exercise to show that the curl of any such field is zero, using its definition in spherical coordinates.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick help!

Comment: I think this answer is a bit backwards, in that it should be emphasized that the claim is false! Otherwise you can give a false impression that your first paragraph is a proof of what OP says.

Answer (score 3):

We know the electromagnetic field is conservative.  A single stationary charge has a spherically symmetric electromagnetic field and is of course conservative; however, the field of *two* charges (or any number of charges, or moving charges) is also conservative but is not spherically symmetric.

Comment: But the field from two charges is the vector sum of two spherically symmetric  fields, each of which can be considered to be acting independently.

Comment: That is true, but the field from two charges is conservative and therefore is a counterexample to "a field can only be conservative if it happens to be spherically symmetric".

Answer (score 1):

A spherically symmetric force field is conservative. But a conservative force field does not have to be spherically symmetric. Example - the force field $\vec F = (x,y,0)$ has cylindrical symmetry but not spherical symmetry.